# Convert data from API server to protobuf error with Dart & Flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart, protocol-buffers

```
Future<dynamic> fetchNews(String lid, String realsize) async {
  String url = "http://192.168.55.101:8000/todo";

  final response =
  await http.get(Uri.parse(url),
    headers: <String, String>{
      // "Content_Type" : "application/x-protobuf"
    },
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    whatNewsMsg data = whatNewsMsg.fromJson(json.decode(response.body.toString()));
    print("data: " + data.title); // ====> Here I get error
  
    return response.body.toString();
  } else {
    throw Exception('Unable to fetch news from the REST API');
  }
}
```

Comment: Could u add your error code?

Comment: Have you tried to add a breakpoint and debug you code, check what is the value of `response.body`, `data` ?

Answer (score 0):

```dart
var data = whatNewsMsg.create()..mergeFromProto3Json(jsonDecode(response.body));
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?